# Unmarshall with JaxB in a Web Service (Soap) Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I have been really struggling with JaxB and the JaxWs on netbeans. 
if i unmarshal the using java classes on a plain java web application, i get the results of  my xml files printed. 
If i then use the same unmarshalling code in a soap webservice method, and  do the web service test a null value is always returned.

How do i unmarshal an xml file in a webservice method on netbeans?

here's my webservice method code part:

```
   @WebMethod(operationName = "getData")
public String getData() {

    try {
        //List<String> listing = new ArrayList();
        StringBuilder str =  new StringBuilder();
        FlightList flights = new FlightList();
        javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbCtx = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(flights.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller();
        flights = (FlightList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.File("flights.xml")); //NOI18N
        for (Flight f : flights.getAvailableFlight()) {
                  str.append(f.getDestinationCity());


        }
        String myString =  str.toString();
        return myString;
    } catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException ex) {
        // XXXTODO Handle exception
        System.out.println("Error occured" + ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

and here's a sample of my schema

```
<xsd:complexType name="Flight">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="aircraftVendor" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="aircraftCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>   
        <xsd:element name="aircraftType" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="fare" type="tns:Fare"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
```

```
<xsd:element name="FlightList">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence >
            <xsd:element name="availableFlight" type="tns:Flight" minOccurs="0"    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="Fare">
    <xsd:attribute name="amount" type="tns:Value" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I would appreciate any help, guide at this moment..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you return myString instead of null as your last line of code instead of within your try catch block.

Comment: it still returns null and doesn't seem to initialize the jaxb try block at all

Comment: Did your server log print any error then as the try wasn't executed your catch should

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that may be the problem:

**Problem Area #1 - Use of `java.io.File`**

You can't be sure where the working directory will be when you deploy your application.  Instead of loading the XML as a file:

```
flights = (FlightList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.File("flights.xml"))
```

Load it from the `ClassLoader`.

```
InputStream xml = FlightList.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("flights.xml");
FlightList flightList = (FlightList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
xml.close();
```

**Problem Area #2 - `JAXBContext` May Not be Aware of the Correct `ClassLoader`**

Make sure you pass in a `ClassLoader` when creating the `JAXBContext` on a package name.  You also need to be sure that package contains a `jaxb.index` file or an `ObjectFactory` class.

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(FlightList.class.getPackage().getName(), FlightList.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: thanks for this, i have done all you advised, now i am getting this exception: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.<clinit>(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:550)

Comment: @Ttola - What application server are you in?

Comment: glassfish 3.1.2 on netbeans 7.3